# I want to generate a mesh from a point cloud in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mesh, point-clouds, mayavi

I have a point cloud from different parts of the human body, like an eye and I want to do a mesh. I tried to use Mayavi and Delaunay but I don't get a good mesh. The points of the cloud are in total disorder.
I have my point cloud in .npz file

[image]

Using Mayavi

[image]

Then I want to save my model in an obj or stl file, but first I want to generate the mesh.
What do you recommend me to use, do I need a special library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use pyvista to do the 3D interpolation. You need however to manually play with the alpha parameter that controls the distance under which two points are linked.

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

# points is a 3D numpy array (n_points, 3) coordinates of a sphere
cloud = pv.PolyData(points)
cloud.plot()

volume = cloud.delaunay_3d(alpha=2.)
shell = volume.extract_geometry()
shell.plot()
```

[image: cloud viz]

[image: mesh after delaunay interpolation]

Answer (score 4):

If your points are "are in total disorder", and if you want to generate a mesh, then you need some interpolation from the cloud of points to the somehow structured grid points of the mesh..

In the 2-dimensional case matplotlib's triangulation can be a help: 
[matplotlib's triangulation 2dim](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/triplot_demo.html).

In the 3-dimensional case there are 2 options. Depending on the data, you might want to interpolate them to a 3-dimensional surface. Then [matplotlib's trisurf3d](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo2.html) can be a help.

If you need a 3-dimensional volume grid then you have probably to look for a FEM (finite element) grid, e.g. [FEnics](https://fenicsproject.org/)

An example of interpolating a 3-dimensional field with scipy for contouring can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419451/3d-contour-plot-from-data-using-mayavi-python?rq=1)

Comment: I want to do it using tetrahedralization or splines but I can not find any way to do it from my point cloud. Yes, of course I have a data set in npz format.

Comment: I have another question, Can I use geomdl to generate the mesh using nurb function?

Comment: I have never used it, so I have no experiences, but following the docs geomdl sounds good. It has procedures for surface grids and for volume grids. (What do you want to achieve actually ?)

Comment: I only want to generate a mesh from my point cloud, in the same way that MeshLab does from a cloud of any points.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
**Data**

Let's use the capitals of Europe. We read them in from Excel with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
dg0 = pd.read_excel('psc_StaedteEuropa_coord.xlsx')  # ,header=None
dg0.head()

    City    Inhabit     xK          yK
0   Andorra 24574.0     42.506939   1.521247
1   Athen   664046.0    37.984149   23.727984
2   Belgrad 1373651.0   44.817813   20.456897
3   Berlin  3538652.0   52.517037   13.388860
4   Bern    122658.0    46.948271   7.451451
```

**Grid by triangulation**

We use [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) for that. For a 3-dim example see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243563/creating-a-triangulation-for-use-in-matplotlibs-plot-trisurf-with-matplotlib-tr) and [HERE](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) or [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/meshing-3d-surface-data-in-python) (CGAL has a Python wrapper)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
yk, xk, city = np.array(dg0['xK']), np.array(dg0['yK']), np.array(dg0['City'])
X1 = np.vstack((xk,yk)).T
tri = Delaunay(X1)
```

**Graphics**

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#--- grafics -------
figX = 25; figY = 18
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(figX, figY), facecolor='white')

myProjection = ccrs.PlateCarree()
ax = plt.axes(projection=myProjection)
ax.stock_img()
ax.set_extent([-25, 40, 35, 65], crs=myProjection)

plt.triplot(X1[:,0], X1[:,1], tri.simplices.copy(), color='r', linestyle='-',lw=2)
plt.plot(X1[:,0], X1[:,1], 's', color='w')

plt.scatter(xk,yk,s=1000,c='w')
for i, txt in enumerate(city):
    ax.annotate(txt, (X1[i,0], X1[i,1]), color='k', fontweight='bold')

plt.savefig('Europe_A.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this example? https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_surface_from_irregular_data.html

The relevant part is here

```
# Visualize the points
pts = mlab.points3d(x, y, z, z, scale_mode='none', scale_factor=0.2)

# Create and visualize the mesh
mesh = mlab.pipeline.delaunay2d(pts)
surf = mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh)
```

Comment: I've already tried with it, the second image is the result.
I think there is not such a simple method to make this mesh. I also have other parts of the human body like a skull and a brain.