# Visualizing 3D hulls around clusters in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, cluster-analysis, mayavi.mlab

**Problem**
I have a dataset consiting of 3D coordinates (x,y,z) and I want to visualize the hull of *each cluster separately*, conserving complex spatial structures of the data, such as in the following examples:
[image: A) Example image]
[image: B) Example image]

**What I have tried:**

- matplotlib's convex hull: This does not seem to be able to conserve the spatial structure such as "holes" or rings, but instead builds a convex hull around all given data points
- mayavi's mlab: This seems to work well for continuous functions, such as np.sin(x)*np.cos(x)*np.sin(z) for example, but not for datasets of discrete points as in my case.

Comment: Try the approach outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25354417/1862861, i.e., convert the points into a 3d KDE based in the density of points, evaluate the KDE on a grid, and then use mayavi to make a density plot (as in that answer, or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424035/1862861).

Comment: I followed this and I get a density plot, which is not quite what I need. What I need is something as displayed in the images above, ie sharp surfaces, contrary to a density plot

Comment: The answer in the second link plots contours, which are surfaces. It just plots 8 of them at a low opacity. Presumably, plotting only one contour with full opacity yields a "proper" surface.

Comment: However, while density estimation with contour estimation is not a bad way to go about the problem (as proposed by @matt-pitkin), a refinement would be to use the marching cube algorithm. scikit-image has an implementation, tutorial [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html).

Comment: See also [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60690334/2912349) for other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example, based on the answers to [How to plot a 3D density map in python with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286811/how-to-plot-a-3d-density-map-in-python-with-matplotlib) and [3D Contour plot from data using Mayavi / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419451/3d-contour-plot-from-data-using-mayavi-python), is to use a Gaussian KDE and generate a 3D contour plot of the output using [mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.contour3d):

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
from mayavi.mlab import contour3d

import numpy as np

# generate some random points
npoints = 10_000

x = np.random.rand(npoints)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x * 0.75 + 0.1) + 0.4 * np.random.randn(len(x))
z = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x * 0.3 + 0.6) + np.sin(2 * np.pi * y) + 0.4 * np.random.randn(len(x))

# construct a Gaussian KDE
xyz = np.vstack([x, y, z])
kde = gaussian_kde(xyz)

# evaluate the KDE on a grid
xmin, ymin, zmin = x.min(), y.min(), z.min()
xmax, ymax, zmax = x.max(), y.max(), z.max()
xi, yi, zi = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:30j, ymin:ymax:30j, zmin:zmax:30j]
coords = np.vstack([item.ravel() for item in [xi, yi, zi]])
density = kde(coords).reshape(xi.shape)

# create the contour plot (for some reason contours must be at least
# 3 to show anything!)
contour3d(xi, yi, zi, density, contours=3, transparent=True)
```

This produces:

[image]

I'm sure a lot could be done within mayavi to prettify this.